# Mapbox map in ui-bootstrap tab not loading tiles

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, mapbox

I'm trying to put a mapbox map inside an angular-ui-bootstrap tab, and it seems that some/most of the tiles are not getting loaded upon initialization, and are not being requested as you pan around on the map. Outside of the ui-bootstrap tabset, the maps work just fine.

No errors are being thrown, but looking at the requests for the tiles, many of them are just not being requested for some reason. I'm not even sure how to debug this one.

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

[Here is a plunkr showing the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpkKZ0sawN9mIGlmxrpZ?p=preview)

And here is an example angular app that will show the problem

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
app.controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.val = 123
}]);
app.directive('myMap', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: "<div id='map_container'></div>", 
      link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
        mapDiv = elem.find('#map_container')
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVwdGlsaWN1cyIsImEiOiJlSWZtN1hZIn0.FfT3RxbfRYv4LIjBxXG5fw';
        var map = L.mapbox.map(mapDiv[0], 'examples.map-i86nkdio')
          .setView([40, -74.50], 9);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: This has something to do with resize event, after window resize everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map gets initialized when the mapcontainer is not visible, that's why it fails. You're on the right path with calling `invalidateSize` but you need to do that when the tab becomes visible. I see you've already setup an event which you could hook into in your directive link function:

```
$scope.$on('tabSelect:map', function (t) {
    $timeout(function () {
        map.invalidateSize(true);
    });
});
```

It doesn't work without the timeout. It needs some sort of delay so the tab is complete visible before firing `invalidateSize`. Here's an updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gzwx2pZ1GjBZDE8Utxfl?p=preview

Comment: Yup, the timeout is the ticket. gracias.